# How to know which indexes to create on which columns in a sql table?

Tags: mysql

```
Shipment(shipid(Primary key), customer, product, fromwarehouse, towarehouse, date, quantity)
```

Your workload consists of 100000 daily queries of type QA, 100000 daily queries of type QB, and 1000 daily inserts of type QX

**QA queries are of the form:**

```
SELECT * FROM Shipment WHERE fromwarehouse = ? AND towarehouse = ? AND product = ? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

**QB queries are of the form:**

```
SELECT quantity FROM Shipment WHERE date = ? AND product = ?
```

**QX queries are of the form:**

```
INSERT INTO Shipment VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

**The DB Administrator is considering building zero or more of the following indexes and has asked you for advice:**

CREATE INDEX ship_customer ON Shipment(customer)

CREATE INDEX ship_date ON Shipment(date)

CREATE INDEX ship_product ON Shipment(product)

CREATE INDEX ship_warehouse ON Shipment(fromwarehouse, towarehouse)

CREATE INDEX ship_date_product ON Shipment(date, product)

CREATE INDEX ship_product_date ON Shipment(product, date)

CREATE INDEX ship_allbydate ON Shipment(date, product, fromwarehouse, towarehouse, quantity, customer, shipid)

**(a) Which of the above indexes that could be used by queries of type QA?  (List their names)**

Not sure which indexes to create? Would this be right?

1. CREATE INDEX ship_date ON Shipment(date)
2. CREATE INDEX ship_product ON Shipment(product)
3. CREATE INDEX ship_warehouse ON Shipment(fromwarehouse, towarehouse)
4. CREATE INDEX ship_product_date ON Shipment(product, date)

**(b) Which of the above indexes that could be used by queries of type QB?  (List their names)**

1. CREATE INDEX ship_date_product ON Shipment(date, product)
2. CREATE INDEX ship_allbydate ON Shipment(date, product, fromwarehouse, towarehouse, quantity, customer, shipid)
3. CREATE INDEX ship_date ON Shipment(date)

**(c) Which indexes would you recommend building?  (List their names)**

1. CREATE INDEX ship_customer ON Shipment(customer)
2. CREATE INDEX ship_date_product ON Shipment(date, product)
3. CREATE INDEX ship_warehouse ON Shipment(fromwarehouse, towarehouse)
4. CREATE INDEX ship_allbydate ON Shipment(date, product, fromwarehouse, towarehouse, quantity, customer, shipid)

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), and the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: Is this a job interview question or a homework assignment?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following index will speed up QB queries:

```
create index ix1 on shipment (product, fromwarehouse, towarehouse);
```

The following index will speed up QB queries:

```
create index ix2 on shipment (product, date);
```

For even greater performance (only if needed) you can use

```
create index ix2b on shipment (product, date, quantity);
```

QX queries have little to no relevance on the indexes.